# Rails 4, MySql & CarrierWave 0.9.0 - Image Not Uploading, Nothing Processing or Happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am really stuck on this one, when I attach an image to a CarrierWave model & then save the model, nothing is happening - there are no signs of the image being processed, the model does not respond to any CarrierWave methods such as .url - it seems like it does not know CarrierWave exists

The model:

```
class Graphic < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :graphic, GraphicUploader
end
```

The model table has a varchar field called image.

The Uploader:

```
class GraphicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :search_results_thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [75, 294]
  end
end
```

When I do the following from the console:

```
g = Graphic.new
g.image = File.open("webphoto.jpeg")
g.save
```

all that happens is I see a new Graphics entry being persisted:

```
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `graphics` (`created_at`, `image`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-01-19 03:38:48', '--- !ruby/object:File {}\n', '2014-01-19 03:38:48')
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Don't have much experience with CarrierWave, but it looks like your implementation is not creating the correct image -- it's trying to save a Ruby object into the DB

Comment: I have the same problem, any fix?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this. I am having thesame problem.